# How to check the user has logged in a domain or not in the linux shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, dns

In my project, the user linux machine will be joined the windows domain.
My shell script need to check the user has logged in the domain or local host.

If the user logged in a domain, I need to get the current domain name that the user logged in; otherwise, I need to get the host name.

I have tried the command "hostname -d", but it will return the domain name always if the linux machine has joined a domain, even the user logged in the local host.

Anybody can give some clues please?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have a feeling you would get more answers if you ask at unix.stackexchange.com — remove the question here, and ask there.

Comment: I am serious, yw5643. Peoples there much better acknowledged with GNU/Linux internals *(the reason is obvious ;)* Also newer questions posted with a slower rate than in SO, allowing to more people to see your question.

Comment: I have asked this question in the unix.stackexchange.com.